# In bootstrap justify-content-sm-center not working as expected

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

In bootstrap 5 justify-content-sm-center is not working as expected. I want to centerlize a particular div in smaller screens (say below 578px) and I applied this to that particular division. But its not working. When I exapnd the screen size to more than 576px, it starts working. In the bootstrap css the media query is like this

```
@media (min-width: 576px)
.justify-content-sm-center {
    justify-content: center !important;
}
```

So it will work over 576px only. Whats the resolution ?

In bootstrap 5 justify-content-sm-center is not working as expected.ie not working in smaller sceen sizes

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is thought mobile-first so if we refer to the [available breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/breakpoints/#available-breakpoints), if you need your elements to be centered under 576px you need to use `.justify-content-center`. And after 576px, so with a *sm* class you can specify another behavior.

In other words, you could do the following to have your content centered when <=576px and then left aligned (in LTR) when >576px.

```html
<div class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-sm-start">
  Flex item
</div>
```